# App Store shows wrong app version for review comment

Tags: ios-appstore

Behind each review there is a version like this (v1.5). I've encountered some comments which clearly use a newer version then it is shown. How is this possible ?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or provide more information?

Comment: In version 2.4.1 of my app I added a prompt to ask people to rate/review my app. 1600 people have done so, but all the reviews are in the App Store for version 2.3.1! The App Store must be marking the reviews incorrectly.

Comment: @kukudas: In the cases you've found, were the apps upgraded to be universal binaries, and the reviews are for the pre-universal version?

Comment: What do you mean by universal binary?

Comment: @kukudas: A single app that works on both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: No. Only for iPhone. But the binary was bigger due to 64 bit support.